# What are common examples for Paré's list of double categories?

Tags: higher-category-theory

In Robert Paré's 2018 presentation "Double Categories: The best thing since slice categories", the [slides](https://www.mta.ca/%7Errosebru/FMCS2018/Slides/Pare1.pdf) non-exhaustively give the following listing of interesting situations where double categories arise:

- External/internal
- *Total/partial* (restriction categories; e.g. **Pfn** & **Set**)
- Deterministic/stochastic
- Classical/quantum
- Linear/smooth
- Classical/intuitionistic
- *Lax/oplax* (**MonCat**)
- Strong/weak
- *Horizontal/vertical* (categories of quintets, categories of commuting squares)

I didn't attend the presentation, so I don't know the examples that were used; **what are typical examples for each of these situations?** I felt that this was small enough for one single question, particularly since somebody might have Paré's original examples, but won't complain if it needs to be split up.

I already know a family of examples for "total/partial"; every restriction category ([nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/restriction+category)) can be rearranged into a double category. Also, for "lax/oplax", I gather that the 2-category **MonCat** of monoidal categories and lax monoidal functors can be turned into a double category with oplax monoidal functors as the other kind of morphism. The slides give examples of generic horizontal-and-vertical-arrow constructions too.